# Checking for rvm Ruby versions

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

As it is going to be used as part of some automation and not just at the command line I was wondering if it could be improved at all.

Improve would mean any of:

- handle sad cases better
- handle error better
- report errors better
- better able to work on multiple linux OS including OSX

Improve would NOT mean:

- shorter code
- short variable names
- Linux shell version specific tricks or shortcuts
- allowing for rvm not being present (checked elsewhere)

```
function make_sure_rvm_rubies_installed() {

rvm list > $TMP/local_ruby_versions.txt
local_ruby_versions=(1.8.7 1.9.3)

for version in "${local_ruby_versions[@]}"
do
  cat $TMP/local_ruby_versions.txt | grep -q $version
  version_search_result=$?
  if [ $version_search_result = 0 ]
  then
    echo "Required RVM Ruby version $version confirmed as present on this machine"
  else
    echo "*** EXITING SMOKE TEST *** - not all required ruby versions are present in RVM"
    echo "Please install RVM ruby version: $version and then re-run this program"
    exit
  fi
done
if [ $? = 0 ]
  then echo "All required Ruby Versions confirmed as present locally"
fi
}

make_sure_rvm_rubies_installed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `make_sure_rvm_rubies_installed` describes very well what the function does,
but it's a bit too much.
Maybe `check_installed_rubies` would be good enough.

---

You didn't indent the body of the function.
It's better to indent the inner part of large `{ ... }` blocks for readability.

No need to use the `function` keyword when declaring functions, though you can if you like.

---

Instead of `cat ... | grep` it's better to omit the `cat` and use the file as a parameter of `grep`.

No need to save the exit code of the `grep` in the `version_search_result` variable,
you can do this directly:

```
  if grep -q $version $TMP/local_ruby_versions.txt
  then
    echo "Required RVM Ruby version $version confirmed as present on this machine"
  else
    echo "*** EXITING SMOKE TEST *** - not all required ruby versions are present in RVM"
    echo "Please install RVM ruby version: $version and then re-run this program"
    exit
  fi
```

The `exit` there is a bit unexpected.
The script could be reusable if you `return 1` instead,
to give a chance to the caller to recover gracefully if necessary.
(In your example use case it doesn't matter, but this is a tip for the future.)

---

I'm not sure what you're expecting from the `$?` check in this code:

> ```
> for version in "${local_ruby_versions[@]}"
> do
>   # ...
> done
> if [ $? = 0 ]
>   then echo "All required Ruby Versions confirmed as present locally"
> fi
> ```

When a version is not found the original loop exits the entire script (I recommended above to return from the function).
So in case of failures this `if` is not reached.
Otherwise the last command to evaluate is an `echo`,
which should just succeed,
so this `if` condition seems pointless, you can omit it.

---

Although arrays are cool, and it's great that you can use them,
in simple situations like this I would use a normal variable:

```
local_ruby_versions='1.8.7 1.9.3'

for version in $local_ruby_versions; do ...; done
```

---

You create the file temporary file `$TMP/local_ruby_versions.txt` but you don't clean it up when finished.